# Laravel validation of request (not parameters)

Tags: laravel

I have a `POST` route: `/tasks/{task}/start`, which claims the task for the user. But before claiming, I need to validate that the task hasn't already been started (potentially by someone else).

Laravel provides excellent support for validation of request parameters.
If there are any problems with the parameters, then laravel uses clever magic to communicate those errors. If the request was made with Ajax, then a failed validation will result in a nicely formatted json with the error. If the request was made from the web, then it will redirect you back `withErrors`.

I want the above behavior, but for validating whether the requested model is in the right state to be modified.

Right now I could do something like:

```
public function start(Request $request, Task $task) {
    if ($task->isStarted()) {
        if ($request->isAjax()) {
            abort(400, "The task was already started");
        } else {
            redirect()->back()->withErrors("The task was already started");
        } 
    }
    // Task is not started. Let's start it...
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is some kind of native support for validating a request by the state of the model, and letting Laravel handle the communication of the error.

**EDIT**

I found another solution, but it seems rather clumsy:

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [])->after(function ($validator) use ($task) {
    if ($task->isStarted()) {
            $validator->errors()->add('task', 'The task was already started');
    }
})->validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Laravel Policies/Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/authorization#introduction).

The end result will look like this:

```php
public function start(Request $request, Task $task) 
{
    $this->authorize('start', $task);

    // Task is not started. Let's start it...
}
```

How you achive this? This is accomplished defining a policy. Let's create a `TaskPolicy`.

## Generate it

Run in console:

```php
php artisan make:policy TaskPolicy
```

## Register it

**app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**

```php
protected $policies = [
    \App\Task::class => \App\TaskPolicy::class,
];
```

#### Customize it

**app/Policies/TaskPolicy.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Task;

class TaskPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given task can be started/claimed by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Task  $task
     * @return bool
     */
    public function start(User $user, Task $task)
    {
        // do your checks here.. you have access to the authenticated user and task

        return !$task->isStarted();
    }
}
```

## Apply it

As mentioned in the beggining:

```php
public function start(Request $request, Task $task) 
{
    $this->authorize('start', $task);

    // Task is not started. Let's start it...
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization) for more info. You might want to use Gates if you are only doing this once.

This error will be returned as `json` or `html` automatically if the authorization fails. It will return `403` error.

**EDIT**

You can of course handle the authorization differently in your controller.

Instead of `$this->authorize('start', $task)` you can do :

```php
if (\Auth::user()->cannot('start', $task) ) {

}
```

Moreover, in your blade view i assume you have something like this

```php
<form method="post" action="route-here">
    <button type="submit">Start Task</button>
</form>
```

what you can do is wrap this with @can..@endcan:

```php
@can('start', @task)
<form method="post" action="route-here">
    <button type="submit">Start Task</button>
</form>
@endcan
```

This way the user will not see the button if they can't start the task.

Comment: But that means that if a user clicks on a "start" button, instead of being redirected back and been shown a human readable error, they will be taken to a 403 page, which is not the desired behavior

Comment: The "@can" part doesn't solve the issue. I'm trying to prevent a race condition, where a user tries to claim a stage that might have already been claimed by someone else. At the time they loaded the page, the task might very well be unstarted